# Check if all elements of a list are in a big single element list

Tags: python, list

```
List1 = ['error please notify us immediately services page com page run policy report date time est valuation date 02 29 2020 currency accident state due to regulatory considerations some of the content contained in this report financial information run additional reports using']

List2 = ['accident state', 'additional reports','contained']
```

In the above case, I would like to return True, since accident date,  additional reports and contained in List2 are all found in List1.
Note: I cannot split List1 along spaces.

My attempt:

```
for i in s[0]:
     if all(item in [i] for item in ['accident state','additional reports','contained']):
          print(True)
     else:
          print(False)
```

Comment: "accident date" is not in the first list.

Comment: How is `s` defined? And making `List1`  a list is probably not what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Your generator expression used in `all` would be

```
>>> all(i in List1[0] for i in List2)
True
```

Though I'd question if `List1` should instead just a string instead of a list with just one element.